# Publish Android app on a scheduled date time

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to publish an android application. I want that my application should be made public at a give date and time. Hows this can be achieved? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Publish on a scheduled time is not possible yet... I recommend you to publish your app in Beta to test if everything is OK and then move your app to the Production channel when you want to made it public. The change will take 30 minutes to 2 hours.